# AngularJS issue with selecting clicked item with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootstrap-modal

I'd like to only pull the selected item to delete from my `ng-repeat` statement. I can only get all the buttons and all the names to work through `ng-repeat`. Is there any way I can just pull the clicked item name and the clicked item button to delete rather than all of them like in the pic?

[image]

The markup for the modal is posted below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Scope List</title>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

    <!-- FONTS -->
    <script src="https://use.edgefonts.net/vast-shadow:n4:all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.edgefonts.net/vast-shadow:n4:all;megrim.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <!-- FONTS -->

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.css" type="text/css" />

  <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- CSS -->

  </head>


  <body ng-controller="appCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak>
    <!--[if IE]>
      <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <div class="parallax">
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    </div>


    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="alert alert-success fade in alert-dismissable text-center" ng-if="alertMessageAdd">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">×</a>
            <strong>{{item.name}} {{alertMessageAdd}}!</strong>
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-warning fade in alert-dismissable text-center" ng-if="alertMessageUpdate">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">×</a>
            <strong>{{value.name}} {{alertMessageUpdate}}!</strong>
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-danger fade in alert-dismissable text-center" ng-if="alertMessageDelete">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">×</a>
            <strong>{{clickedItem(value.name)}} {{alertMessageDelete}}!</strong>
        </div> 

        <div class="bottom-row text-center">
            <span class="small"> Total :: </span><span class="emphasis large">{{DB.length}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="top-row">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <span class="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i> <input type="text" ng-model="searchs" />
                <span ng-if="searchs.length === 0"><strong>No Results Found ...</strong></span>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-container">
             <md-button type="button" class="md-accent md-raised" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">
                <i class="material-icons">add_box</i> Add </md-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <!-- FIREBASE -->
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <thead>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>            
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Exclusives</th>
            <th>Price (USD)</th>
            <th>Added</th>
            <th>Edit / Delete</th>
          </thead>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="value in DB | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchs">
          <td><a href="{{value.link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{value.image}}" class="img-responsive" width="50" height="50"></a></td>
          <td>{{value.id}}</td>
          <td>{{value.name}}</td>
          <td>{{value.size}}</td>
          <td>{{value.description}}</td>
          <td>{{value.exclusives.toString()}}</td>
          <td>{{value.price | currency: '$'}}</td>
          <td>{{CurrentDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
          <td>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateModal" ng-click="edit(value)"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></md-button>
            <!-- Delete Modal Popup -->
            <md-button class="md-raised md-warn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></md-button> 

            <!--<md-button class="md-raised md-warn" type="button" ng-click="delete(value)"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></md-button>-->

          </td>
       </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- FIREBASE -->



    <!-- Modal Add Form -->
    <div id="Modal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                  <form id="Form" name="Form" type="submit" ng-submit="add(value)" novalidate>
                        <md-content>

                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                          <label>ID</label>
                          <input required name="ID" type="number" ng-model="app.id">
                          <div ng-messages="Form.ID.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> ID is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                          <label>Name</label>
                          <input required name="Name" ng-model="app.name">
                          <div ng-messages="Form.Name.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> name is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>

                          <div layout="row">
                          <div layout="column" flex="50">
                        <md-input-container id="size" class="md-block">
                          <label>Size</label>
                          <md-select name="Size" ng-model="app.size" required>
                                <md-option value='3"'>3"</md-option>
                                <md-option value='4.5"'>4.5"</md-option>
                                <md-option value='6"'>6"</md-option>
                                <md-option value='7.5"'>7.5"</md-option>
                                <md-option value='9.5"'>9.5"</md-option>
                                <md-option value='11"'>11"</md-option>
                                <md-option value='12"'>12"</md-option>
                          </md-select>
                          <div ng-messages="Form.Size.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> size is required.</div>
                          </div>
                         </md-input-container>
                            </div>
                        <div layout="column" flex="50">
                        <md-input-container>
                          <label>Price (USD)</label>
                          <input required name="Price" ng-model="app.price">
                            <div ng-messages="Form.Price.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> price is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                      </div>
                      </div>

                      <div layout="column">
                      <md-input-container class="md-block">
                        <label>Description</label>
                        <input md-maxlength="200" required name="description" ng-model="app.description">
                        <div ng-messages="Form.description.$error">
                          <div ng-message="required"> description is required.</div>
                          <div ng-message="md-maxlength"> description must be less than 200 characters long.</div>
                        </div>
                      </md-input-container>      
                      </div>

                          <md-input-container class="md-block">
                          <label>Exclusives</label>
                          <md-select name="exclusives" multiple ng-model="app.exclusives" required>
                            <md-option value="Amazon">Amazon</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Claires">Claires</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Curly Dani">Curly Dani</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Enesco">Enesco</md-option>                            
                            <md-option value="Gund">Gund</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Hey Chickadee">Hey Chickadee</md-option>
                            <md-option value="It's Sugar">It's Sugar</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Macys">Macys</md-option>
                            <md-option value="New Egg">New Egg</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Not Available">Not Available</md-option>
                          </md-select>
                           <div ng-messages="Form.exclusives.$error">   
                            <div ng-message="required">Please pick at least one  exclusive or N/A.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>

                       <div layout="column">
                        <md-input-container>
                          <label>Item Link</label>
                          <input required name="Link" ng-model="app.link">
                          <div ng-messages="Form.Link.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> item link is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                      </div>     

                      <div layout="column">
                        <md-input-container>
                          <label>Item Image Link</label>
                          <input required name="image" ng-model="app.image">
                          <div ng-messages="Form.image.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> image link is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                      </div>      


                    </form>
                  </md-content>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="pull-left" layout="row" layout-align="end center">

             <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" ng-disabled="Form.$invalid" ng-click="add(value)"><md-icon class="material-icons ng-scope">add_box</md-icon> Add</md-button>

                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                    <md-button type="button" class="md-accent md-raised" data-dismiss="modal"><md-icon class="material-icons">close</md-icon> Close</md-button>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Add Form -->



    <!-- Modal Update Form -->
    <div id="updateModal" class="modal fade out">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Update a </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                  <form name="UpdateForm" ng-submit="save(value)" novalidate>
                        <md-content>

                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                          <label>ID</label>
                          <input required name="ID" type="number" ng-model="app.id">
                          <div ng-messages="UpdateForm.ID.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> ID is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                          <label>Name</label>
                          <input required name="Name" ng-model="app.name">
                          <div ng-messages="UpdateForm.Name.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> name is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>

                          <div layout="row">
                          <div layout="column" flex="50">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                          <label>Size</label>
                          <md-select name="Size" ng-model="app.size" required>
                            <md-option value='3"'>3"</md-option>
                            <md-option value='4.5"'>4.5"</md-option>
                            <md-option value='6"'>6"</md-option>
                            <md-option value='7.5"'>7.5"</md-option>
                            <md-option value='9.5"'>9.5"</md-option>
                            <md-option value='11"'>11"</md-option>
                            <md-option value='12"'>12"</md-option>
                          </md-select>
                          <div ng-messages="UpdateForm.Size.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> size is required.</div>
                          </div>
                         </md-input-container>
                            </div>
                        <div layout="column" flex="50">
                        <md-input-container>
                          <label>Price (USD)</label>
                          <input required name="Price" ng-model="app.price">
                            <div ng-messages="UpdateForm.Price.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> price is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                      </div>
                      </div>

                      <div layout="column">
                      <md-input-container class="md-block">
                        <label>Description</label>
                        <input md-maxlength="200" required name="description" ng-model="app.description">
                        <div ng-messages="UpdateForm.description.$error">
                          <div ng-message="required"> description is required.</div>
                          <div ng-message="md-maxlength"> description must be less than 200 characters long.</div>
                        </div>
                      </md-input-container>      
                      </div>

                          <md-input-container class="md-block">
                          <label>Exclusives</label>
                          <md-select name="exclusives" multiple ng-model="app.exclusives" required>
                            <md-option value="Amazon">Amazon</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Claires">Claires</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Curly Dani">Curly Dani</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Enesco">Enesco</md-option>                            
                            <md-option value="Gund">Gund</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Hey Chickadee">Hey Chickadee</md-option>
                            <md-option value="It's Sugar">It's Sugar</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Macys">Macys</md-option>
                            <md-option value="New Egg">New Egg</md-option>
                            <md-option value="Not Available">Not Available</md-option>
                          </md-select>
                           <div ng-messages="UpdateForm.exclusives.$error"> 
                            <div ng-message="required">Please pick at least one  exclusive or N/A.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>

                       <div layout="column">
                        <md-input-container>
                          <label>Item Link</label>
                          <input required name="Link" ng-model="app.link">
                          <div ng-messages="UpdateForm.Link.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> item link is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                      </div>     

                      <div layout="column">
                        <md-input-container>
                          <label>Item Image Link</label>
                          <input required name="image" ng-model="app.image">
                          <div ng-messages="UpdateForm.image.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required"> image link is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                      </div>      


                    </form>
                  </md-content>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="pull-left" layout="row" layout-align="end center">


             <md-button class="md-warn md-raised" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="save(value)"><md-icon class="ng-scope material-icons">save</md-icon> Save</md-button>

                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                    <md-button type="button" class="md-accent md-raised" data-dismiss="modal"><md-icon class="material-icons">close</md-icon> Close</md-button>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Update Form -->


    <!-- Modal Yes/No -->
    <div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete ?</h4>
            </div>


            <div class="modal-body">

                <h4 class="text-center" ng-repeat="value in DB">Are you sure you want to delete <strong><em>{{value.name}}</em></strong>?</h4>

            </div>


                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div layout="row" layout-align="end center">

                        <md-button class="md-warn md-raised pull-left" type="button" data-toggle="modal" ng-repeat="value in DB" ng-click="delete(value)" data-dismiss="modal"><md-icon class="ng-scope material-icons">delete_forever</md-icon> Yes</md-button>

                        <md-button type="button" class="md-raised md-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="material-icons">not_interested</i> No</md-button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Yes/No -->


    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/parallax/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/parallax/parallax.js"></script>

    <!-- AngularJS Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase -->

    <!-- APP JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/appCtrl.js"></script>
    <!-- APP JS -->
    <!-- JS -->

  </body>
</html>
```

and the controller code is here

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $firebase) 
{
/* Firebase Database Connect */
var ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/");
var sync = $firebase(ref);

$scope.DB = sync.$asArray();

/* Page Title */
$scope.title='Scope List';    


/* CRUD Labels for Events */
$scope.selectItem = function(item) {
  console.log(item);
  $scope.clickedItem = item;
}


/* Date Added (Need to change to time submitted not current time) */
$scope.CurrentDate = new Date();

/* CRUD Functionality */
$scope.app={id:'',name:'',size:'',description:'',exclusives:'',price:'',status:'',link:'',image:'',added:''}

/* Add Item */
$scope.add=function(){
  $scope.alertMessageAdd = "";

  $scope.DB.$add($scope.app);
  $scope.app={id:'',name:'',size:'',description:'',exclusives:'',price:'',status:'',link:'',image:'',added:''}
  $scope.alertMessageAdd = "New item added successfully!";


  /* Add Form Validation */
  $scope.Form.Name.$error = {
    "required": true
  }

  $scope.Form.ID.$error = {
    "required": true
  }

  $scope.Form.Size.$error = {
    "required": true
  }

  $scope.Form.Price.$error = {
    "required": true
  }

  $scope.Form.description.$error = {
    "required": true
  }

  $scope.Form.exclusives.$error = {
    "required": true
  }

  $scope.Form.Link.$error = {
    "required": true
  }

  $scope.Form.image.$error = {
    "required": true
  }

  $scope.Form.ID = '';
  $scope.Form.Size = '';
  $scope.Form.Price = '';
  $scope.Form.description = '';
  $scope.Form.exclusives = '';
  $scope.Form.Link = '';
  $scope.Form.image = '';


  // reset form and disable error messages
  $scope.Form.$setPristine();
  $scope.Form.$setUntouched();
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#Modal')).modal('hide');
}


/* Save Item */
$scope.save=function(){
  $scope.alertMessageUpdate = "";

  $scope.DB.$save($scope.app);
  $scope.app={id:'',name:'',size:'',description:'',exclusives:'',price:'',status:'',link:'',image:'',added:''}

  $scope.alertMessageUpdate = "item updated successfully!";
}


/* Edit Item */
$scope.edit=function(value){
  $scope.app=value
}


/* Delete Item */
$scope.delete=function(item){
  $scope.alertMessageDelete = "";

  $scope.DB.$remove(item)
  $scope.alertMessageDelete = "item deleted successfully!";
}

/* Size Dropdown */
$scope.size=['3\"','4.5\"','6\"','7.5\"','9.5\"','11\"','"12\"']

/* Exclusives Multi Select */
$scope.exclusives=["Amazon","Claires","Curly Dani","Gund","Hey Chickadee","It\'s Sugar","Macys","New Egg","Not Available"]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer :  I am not aware of the `firebase` thing you are using. However what you intent to achieve should be straight forward in your angular code.
From your `ng-`repeat`segment in html, You should place a`delete` function and 
pass the reference of the current iterator. Something like :

```
<div ng-repeat= "value in DB">
    <div>{{value}}></div><button ng-click="delete(value)"></button>
</div>
```

You have not shared your repeater code, so this is just my guess for delete functionality. But this way you get a particular instance and then you can use it for your alert messages.

Hope this helps. Share your repeater code if things do not clear up yet.

**Further explained for OP:**

You have this button on which you open your model:

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-warn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></md-button>
```

Then you have this repeater in your delete modal:

```
 <div class="modal-body">

                <h4 class="text-center" ng-repeat="value in DB">Are you sure you want to delete <strong><em>{{value.name}}</em></strong>?</h4>

            </div>
```

The problem is you are repeating all values in your DB using `ng-repeat="value in DB"`. You should not be doing this, rather you should be pulling the clicked value out of your button. To pull this you can place a `click` listener on your `md-button`. Like:

```
  <md-button class="md-raised md-warn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" ng-click="getValueToDelete(value)"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></md-button>
```

This function gets value and you can store it somewhere in your scope. In this case I am using rootScope but you should try doing something else.

```
$scope.getValueToDelete = function(value){
   $rootScope.valueToDelete = value
}
```

And in your modal, you should use only this value instead of `ng-repeat = value in DB`. Something like :

```
<div class="modal-body">

                <h4 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete <strong><em>{{valueToDelete.name}}</em></strong>?</h4>

            </div>
```

This way you get only one value in your modal. Hope it now seems useful.

Comment: Hi, 

I'll the full markup, but I'm looking for a way to only post the name and the delete button of the clicked item. As it stands the layout is like so 

delete button in table opens delete modal with yes or no and if you click yes it deletes permanently. I can only get it to show the button and name of all of the db entries, but I only need the clicked item. Is there any way I can only target the clicked item name and clicked item button? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain things. Have a look again